# Mysql Text Search Issues

Tags: php, mysql, search

I am trying to make exact search but getting problem when search with "Sonal", I am getting result from the record has "Sonal" & "personal". When I remove % before var name then getting the result which record start from "Sonal" and doesn't find that text has "Sonal" anywhere.

Here is the query:

```
AND (
       lower(document_text) LIKE '%".$search_name2."%' 
    OR lower(customdoc_name) LIKE '%".$search_name2."%' 
    OR lower(doc_tags) LIKE '%".$search_name2."%'
)
```

Rec. 1 - Personal Certificate
Rec. 2 - Sonal Certificate.

I want only 2nd record return when search with "Sonal".

I am not using FULLTEXT Field.

Comment: Why are you not using a FULLTEXT search?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this may help,

add space back of string or front and back or front only. by this you will get result with "sonal" in case of beginning of string or middle of string or end of string.

```
AND (
       lower(document_text) LIKE '%".$search_name2." %' 
    OR lower(customdoc_name) LIKE '% ".$search_name2." %' 
    OR lower(doc_tags) LIKE ' %".$search_name2."%'
)
```

Comment: :) Nice , I didn't notice about this SPACE :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `REGEXP` try following..

```
AND (
       lower(document_text) REGEXP '[[:<:]]".$search_name2."[[:>:]]' 
    OR lower(customdoc_name) REGEXP '[[:<:]]".$search_name2."[[:>:]]' 
    OR lower(doc_tags) REGEXP '[[:<:]]".$search_name2."[[:>:]]' 
)
```

Performance wise not good.. but you will get exact results..

Answer (score 0):

"%" operator behaves this way only.

It is a wildcard character meaning ANY STRING.
So

1. "%HELL%" will match  "OT**HELL**O" , "HELL" , "HELLO" , "THE_**HELL**" etc
2. "HELL%" will match only words starting with HELL like "HELL","HELLO","HELLOWW", but not "OTHELLO".
3. "%HELL" will match words ending with HELL like "THE_HELL", but not "HELLO" .

Comment: it should be a comment rather than an answer

Comment: @diEcho  why does it qualify more as a comment and less as an answer ?

Comment: @DhruvPathak: it is more of a side note. does not actually answers the question. Its helpful, though. No offense whatsoever. :)